# Locking removable drive?

Tags: winapi, vb6, locking, drives

Friends,
How to **lock/unlock(software based) removable disk/drives** in VB6? I need to know any specific **win32** routines are there for this purpose?

Comment: I heard that we can able to lock/unlock the cd-drive using win32 routine! But i dont get much information about that routines? Is that routine can be used for the removable drives like USB/Flash drives?

Comment: What do you mean by "lock"?  With a CD drive, it should in theory be possible to disable the eject button.  With a USB drive, there is no eject button, you just pull it out, so there's no way to prevent this.

Comment: Locking refers to software based. Not a physical lock. In windows some routines are there to lock/unlock the cd-drive by disabling the eject/close request. Anybody knew about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having used this, I would say that you want to look at the win32  [IOCTL_STORAGE_MEDIA_REMOVAL Control Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363416.aspx) parameter to DeviceIoControl() which  *"..Enables or disables the mechanism that ejects media, for those devices possessing that locking capability..."*

Comment: @ peter M Could you please give the exact function for lock and the same for unlock here.

Comment: All I know is what is in the link that I have posted.  I have never used this function myself.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a file on the removable disk is the simplest way to lock the drive. This can be done with VB6's internal `Open` command, or by declaring the `OpenFile` API and calling that.

I imagine there are ways of locking the drive itself, but it is much easier to lock a file instead.

Comment: By just reading we cant lock the tray... You can able to lock the cd tray.

Answer (score 0):

This will not be of great use to you, but simple proof if can be done [there](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/ioctl/cdrom.txt#773), from linux kernel 2.6 documentation.

An alternative to API, meanwhile, could be [this](http://www.shivaranjan.com/2008/09/29/lock-and-unlock-cd-or-dvd-drives-from-windows/), a software that does just that, lock/unlock CD drives.

Cheers.